# Pandas Groupby, How to keep additional column not in the level or the analysis column?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
DATE    month   hour    val1    val2
1/1/2012    1   1   1   3
1/1/2012    1   2   2   4
1/1/2012    1   3   3   5
1/1/2012    1   4   4   6
1/1/2012    1   5   5   7
1/1/2012    1   6   6   8
1/1/2012    1   7   7   9
1/1/2012    1   8   8   10
1/1/2012    1   9   9   11
1/1/2012    1   10  10  12
1/1/2012    1   11  11  13
1/1/2012    1   12  12  14
1/1/2012    1   13  13  15
1/1/2012    1   14  14  16
1/1/2012    1   15  15  17
1/1/2012    1   16  16  18
1/1/2012    1   17  17  19
1/1/2012    1   18  18  20
1/1/2012    1   19  19  21
1/1/2012    1   20  20  22
1/1/2012    1   21  21  23
1/1/2012    1   22  22  24
1/1/2012    1   23  23  25
1/1/2012    1   24  24  26
1/2/2012    1   1   25  27
1/2/2012    1   2   26  28
1/2/2012    1   3   27  29
1/2/2012    1   4   28  30
1/2/2012    1   5   29  31
1/2/2012    1   6   30  32
```

Suppose the name of the data is df, I have some sql queries:

```
   select  distinct date, 
                    month, 
                    max(val1)  as val1,
                    mean(val2) as val2
       from df
       group by date
      ;
```

I want to replicate it in pandas
I tried:

```
df.groupby('DATE')['val1'].max()   # it works
df.groupby('DATE')['val2'].mean()  # it works
```

I want to combine those two:

```
df.groupby('DATE').agg(['val1'].max(), ['val2'].mean()) # it does't work
```

Also I want to keep "month" column (as a regular column, not index) but I can't figure out where to put it. Is there any easy way (without any merge, join)?
Please help. Thanks.

Additional: my data actually has column with strings. status is the same for each hour of the day.

```
DATE    month   hour    val1    val2    status
1/1/2012    1   1   1   3   okay
1/1/2012    1   2   2   4   okay
1/1/2012    1   3   3   5   okay
1/1/2012    1   4   4   6   okay
1/1/2012    1   5   5   7   okay
1/1/2012    1   6   6   8   okay
1/1/2012    1   7   7   9   okay
1/1/2012    1   8   8   10  okay
1/1/2012    1   9   9   11  okay
1/1/2012    1   10  10  12  okay
1/1/2012    1   11  11  13  okay
1/1/2012    1   12  12  14  okay
1/1/2012    1   13  13  15  okay
...
1/2/2012    1   1   25  27  error
1/2/2012    1   2   26  28  error
1/2/2012    1   3   27  29  error
1/2/2012    1   4   28  30  error
1/2/2012    1   5   29  31  error
1/2/2012    1   6   30  32  error
```

I want to get the summary statistics for val1 and val2 group by DATE. At the same time, keep the "status" column. I can do it very easily using sql. In pandas groupby statement, I found no where to add the column that is not part of the groupby or analysis column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, `agg` takes a dict of {column name -> function}

```
In [35]: df.groupby('DATE').agg({'val1': 'max', 'val2': 'mean'})
Out[35]: 
          val1  val2
DATE                
1/1/2012    24  14.5
1/2/2012    30  29.5
```

Your second one doesn't really make sense as an aggregation. You could hack it with something like

```
In [36]: df.groupby('DATE').agg({'val1': 'max', 'val2': 'mean', 'month': 'max'})
Out[36]: 
          month  val1  val2
DATE                       
1/1/2012      1    24  14.5
1/2/2012      1    30  29.5
```

since *you* know that the month is the same for each `DATE`, but what if there's an error in the data? Something better would be to make `DATE` an array of Datetimes, so that it becomes a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [43]: df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
In [46]: result = df.groupby('DATE').agg({'val1': 'max', 'val2': 'mean'})

In [47]: result['month'] = result.index.month

In [48]: result
Out[48]: 
            val1  val2  month
DATE                         
2012-01-01    24  14.5      1
2012-01-02    30  29.5      1
```